# How to access obscured objects in Xcode

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

In Xcode storyboard, is there any way to move with mouse the view for example, obscured by another view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select it in the document navigator to the left. Double-click and you can use the arrow keys to nudge the position around.

Comment: I see, but there are cases where the path is way long to move it using keypress. For example small object on ipad canvas. Really there is no other way rather than mentioned and explicit coordinates?